# System chooses boot drive seemingly at random

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, bios, multi-boot, xubuntu

I have a system with two identical 1TB harddrives, where I image to a backup drive using the dd command.  When I boot up, though, despite setting harddrive priority in the BIOS, the system sometimes boots the main drive, sometimes boots the backup.  My system dual-boots Xubuntu and Windows XP, if that means anything to you.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any connection between what boots, and what was booted last?

Comment: No, there isn't.  In Linux terms, I only ever want to be sda.  So for example, I'll have sda booted, restart, then sdb will appear.  So I shutdown and try again, which usually then works.

Comment: are you sure it's the BIOS getting the the drives confused?  Xubuntu's *uDev* could be assigning *sda* and *sdb* differently each time.  especially since you're using *dd* to backup -- this would copy the partitions' UUIDs as well, so Xubuntu (and likely WinXP) wouldn't have any way to tell the drives apart.

Answer (score 0):

Quack Quixote is likely correct. I imagine your computer may be detecting them at just slightly different times leading to one being considered `sda` rather than what you expect (`sdb`). If this is the case, the fix is simple: don't use `/dev/sdX` references in your bootloader config or fstab. I prefer using the disk label, but some prefer using UUIDs.

Can you paste your bootloader config in a snippet here so we can determine more accurately if this is the problem?

**Edit**: I just saw how old this thread is; my apologies for the noise. Generally speaking though (for anyone who may encounter this issue in the future), the `/dev/sdX` references are the most likely problem.